# R: ggsurvplot how to remove the flat line before start.time (2 year)

Tags: r, ggplot2

[link for the ggsurvplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2gwB.png)

I have defined the start.time = 2 and xlim = c(2,10). But I don't understand why there is a flat line before 2 years. Actually there is no event_years < 2. Any one can help?

Thanks!

```
event_censor <- c(rep(0,15), 1,0,1,1,0)  
event_years  <- c(10,10,2.37,10,5.87,10,10,10,5.80,
                  10,10,10,10,6.67,5.71,2.01,2.30,3.19,8.75,2.61)
test.df<-as.data.frame(cbind(event_censor,event_years))

ggsurvplot(survfit(Surv(event_years, event_censor) ~ 1, 
                   data = test.df, start.time=2 ), 
           data = test.df,  fun = "event", xlim = c(2,10), break.x.by = 1)
```

Comment: Please try to remove this from your code `, start.time=2`  as you already wrote `xlim = c(2,10)`. If you can provide reproducible data, I will try to help.

Comment: Thanks, Mohamed! I have updated my questions by adding the sample data and simpler codes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the edited code

```
library(survminer);library(survival)
ggsurvplot(survfit(Surv(event_years, event_censor) ~ 1, 
                       data = test.df, start.time=2 ), 
                      data = test.df,  fun = "event", xlim = c(2,10), break.x.by = 1,axes.offset=F)
```

I just added `axes.offset=F`. You might find more details using `??ggsurvplot`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer, but I came here looking for an answer. The problem I had was that I had negative values for some of my time variables, so the KM curve was looking back in time from t = 0 and noting that there were no events. If this happens to anyone, be sure to make sure that all of your time values are positive.